# Magento 2 Runtime Error After Migration to production server

Tags: magento2, runtime

I have been developing using Magento for years and finally jumped into Magento 2.

Everything is setup and running locally well but I've moved the code base to a production server and getting the following error:

Next RuntimeException: Source class `\Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool` for

`Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool\Proxy` generation does not exist. in `/var/www/html/cwu/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:185`

There is a big stacktrace that follows this but no mention of other errors.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Please run below commands on Magento Root folder

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub // Not necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Redis, flush everything with `redis-cli` using `FLUSHDB`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a difference version of your local copy of Magento 2 with your Magento 2 installed on server. It is mentioned here about \Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool.

Source: [Backward-incompatible change from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 on Config Reader #7821](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7821)